# JQueryMobile - Button

Tags: jquery-mobile

How to disable the button in coding using jquery mobile?

```
<div data-role="button" id="val">Value</div>
```

[Note : I want to disable the button in the coding, not in the design time]

Comment: are you asking how to stop a submit action?

Comment: no.. Just , I want to disable the button. If I am disable the button then it will automatically not perform the any events(click)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Live Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LHG4L/5/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="content">
        <input type="button" id="theButton" name="theButton" value="The Button">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#theButton').attr('disabled',true);
```

UPDATE:

Link button example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/gRLYQ/6/

JS

```
var clicked = false;

$('#myButton').click(function() {
    if(clicked === false) {
        $(this).addClass('ui-disabled');
        clicked = true;
        alert('Button is now disabled');
    } 
});

$('#enableButton').click(function() {
    $('#myButton').removeClass('ui-disabled');
    clicked = false; 
});
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">

        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="myButton">Click button</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="enableButton">Enable button</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

NOTE: - http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/buttons/buttons-types.html

> Links styled like buttons have all the same visual options as true
>   form-based buttons below, but there are a few important differences.
>   Link-based buttons aren't part of the button plugin and only just use
>   the underlying buttonMarkup plugin to generate the button styles so
>   the form button methods (enable, disable, refresh) aren't supported.
>   If you need to disable a link-based button (or any element), it's
>   possible to apply the disabled class ui-disabled yourself with
>   JavaScript to achieve the same effect.

Comment: hi.. Thanks.. But Why we cannot the disable the property in the data-role = "button" method? please share your views.

Comment: hmm will have to look at this more, if you find a solution please post.

Comment: I second Girija's question/request, would be great if same would work for <a data-role="button"> - hope it will be in future jqm releases.

Comment: @Mathias updated my answer with a link button example as well

Answer (score 1):

You can and should disable it using both jquery and jquerymobile:

```
$('#theButton').attr('disabled', true);
if ($('#theButton').button) $('#theButton').button('disable')
```

Comment: Use `.prop('disabled', true)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable button using the attribute `class="ui-disabled"` as follows:

```
<a href="index.html" data-role="button" class="ui-disabled">Link button</a>
```