# How to disable form Submit button until fields are filled with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery, html, mobile, jquery-mobile

I've been looking for a solution to disable the form submit button until the required fields are filled. I've found something here at stackoverflow (courtesy of [mblase75](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755966/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-disable-a-forms-submit-button-until-every-required-field)), but it's for standard jQuery and doesn't work with jQuery Mobile.

The reason behind this is that there's a form on a mobile page that requires all fields to be filled before submitting it. Validation is solved via php so it's not a necessary part.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $form = $('#formid'); // cache
    $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true); // disable submit btn
    $form.find(':input').change(function() { // monitor all inputs for changes
         var disable = false;
         $form.find(':input').not('[type="submit"]').each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
            if ($.trim(el.value) === '') {
                    disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
            }
         });
         $form.find(':input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',disable);
        });
    });
```

Sadly I'm not a jQuery guru, and if possible I'd like some help with this.
Also any other suggestions are welcome (even for validation with jQuery mobile).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5854580/jquerymobile-button/5862415#5862415 related

Comment: It's part of the solution, but that's the working part, the button gets disabled but doesn't get enabled once the form is completed.

Comment: Also, jQuery versions:
jQuery: 1.6.4
jQuery Mobile: 1.0RC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#formid');
    var submitBtn = $('#submitBtnId');

    submitBtn.addClass('disable');

    form.submit(function()

        if(validate()) {
            submitBtn.removeClass('disable');
        }

        if(submitBtn.hasClass('disable')) {
            return false;
        }

        else {
            return true;
        }

    });

    function validate() {
        form.find('input, textarea').change(function(){
            // validation goes here if all inputs are validate then return true otherwise false
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may actually be checking the values of other "buttons" like input[type="button"] or input[type="reset"].  These have a blank value unless they are set.  The following code accounts for this (plus a few more caching statements):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $form = $('#formid'), // cache
        $inputs = $form.find(':input'), // MOD extra caching
        $buttons = $inputs.not(':submit, :reset, :button'),
        $fields = $inputs.not($buttons),
        $submits = $buttons.filter(':submit');

    $submits.prop('disabled', true); // disable submit btn
    $fields.keyup(function() { // monitor all inputs for changes, MOD changed to keyup
         var disable = false;
         $fields.each(function(i, el) { // test all inputs for values
            if ($(el).val() === '') { // MOD use jQuery to get value
                    disable = true; // disable submit if any of them are still blank
                    return false; // MOD stop "each" if even one field is blank... less waste
            }
         });
         $submits.prop('disabled',disable);
        });
});
```

This will not account for a group of radio buttons where none were checked, however.